# Show product discount percent in Magento

Tags: product, magento-1.9, image

I would like to show discount percentage on image as badge (refer image 2). I followed the instructions from http://www.customy.com/blog/show-product-discount-percent-in-magento/ and managed to show discount percentage on product page (refer image 1).

I tried:

app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

```
<?php // Discount percents output start ?>
<?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
<?php $_savePercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100); ?>
    <p class="special-price yousave">
        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('You Save:') ?></span>
        <span class="price">
            <?php echo $_savePercent; ?>%
        </span>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now I got result as:

1.
 [image]

Now I need to show discount percentage on product image too like

2.
 [image]

**What should I do to show discount badge on product image?**
I'm using magento 1.9.0.1 RWD theme

Comment: in which page.you want to show it

Comment: I want to show it in on product images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i seen in your question image you need this effect on **product detail page** so have to edit `media.phtml`

```
app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\default\template\catalog\product\view\media.phtml
```

And in that you have to do same coding to get this value. you can make wrapper class which is override to product image with some dynamic text over product image
like as you want.

you can use  css like in this page

http://techdem.centerkey.com/2013/01/ribbon-banner-css-transform-rotate-45.html

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how to position discount % on my product image. Could you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: now I generated image, but don't how to insert it on product image, I guess I need CSS support. Anyhow thank you for your great support.

Comment: fyi, I moved the page to: https://blog.centerkey.com/2013/01/ribbon-banner-css-transform-rotate-45.html

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<?php // Discount percents output start 
$_finalPrice=$_product->getFinalPrice(); 
 $_price=$_product->getPrice();

?>
    <?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
    <?php $_savePercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100); ?>
        <img src="image " alt="<?php echo "Discount % ".$_savePercent; ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php // Discount percent output end ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it on app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml no changes happen on my site.

Comment: There is a typo here: $_price=$_product->getPirce(); should be $_price=$_product->getPrice();
However if using this in price.phtml this shouldn't be necessary

Comment: Instead of percentage how to show " you save : discount amount "  ? @Amit Bera♦

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to show product discount percent next to product price or somewhere on a product page, here's how you do it.

Open **app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/price.phtml**
&
Find:

```
<?php endif; /* if ($_finalPrice == $_price): */ ?>
```

Add above it:

```
<?php // Display Discount percents start ?>
    <?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
    <?php $_savingPercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100); ?>
        <p class="special-price yoursaving">
            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Your Saving:') ?></span>
            <span class="price">
                <?php echo $_savingPercent; ?>%
            </span>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php // Display Discount percent end ?>
```

Comment: my location : C:\wamp\www\abcd\app\design\frontend\default\theme name\template\catalog\product\price.phtml,,   after adding your code, the original price also hiding,, how can i solve this,,

Comment: and also not displayed the price of every product.

Comment: This code is for display discount percentage , Not to Hide price