# Show product discount in percentage Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

Is it possible to display discount percentage in Magento 2.1 as referred to in the thread below? (This is for older versions)

I tried to install the "Display discount" extension from the Mage Extensions Shop, but the extension just causes my entire Configuration section to freeze. Also I spent the entire afternoon searching on Google, but nothing really helpful..

I'm on a tight schedule and working with Magento 2.1 CE.

Any suggestion is welcome!

[Show product discount percent in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33306/show-product-discount-percent-in-magento)

Answer (score 1):

Modifications to certain template files will be needed to show this.

For the category view page copy /magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/produc‌​t/list.phtml to your luma theme within 'Magento_Catalog/templates/product' folder. Find the section:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
```

Then add below code to within this foreach loop:

```
if ($_product->getPrice()>$_product->getFinalPrice()):
    echo '<div class="salebox">-' . number_format((float)(1 - $_product->getSpecialPrice()/$_product->getPrice()) * 100, 0, '.', ''). '%</div>';
endif;
```

Comment: Ok, being reasonable new to Magento, where can I add this? I would like to display the discount to all products that have a special price for certain customer groups.

Comment: have you got a theme?

Comment: I'm using the default Luma theme

Comment: Copy vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml to your luma theme within Magento_Catalog/templates/product then add that code to within the foreach loop for products.

Comment: This will start you off at showing them in category pages. Product pages will be a bit more work but can add that later to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much so far, I will let you know the result!

Comment: I have added that to my answer. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Hello again, I found the file list.phtml and added the code to it. However, I am unsure about the location where to copy the file to. I cannot find it in my Magento2 install... could it be somewher her: /magento2/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend ?

Comment: So if your modifying Luma theme copy to /app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml